Missing Package "gss-ffmpeg"?
System: Ubuntu 22.04, 64 bit, running in Oracle VirtualBox.
I wonder if someone can point me in the right direction.  Trying to install some software that has a dependency on the "gss-ffmpeg" package.  Running:
sudo apt install gss-ffmpeg

reports back the usual:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package gss-ffmpeg is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'gss-ffmpeg' has no installation candidate

If I run:
sudo apt install gss*

I see a line:
Note: selecting 'gss-ffmpeg' for glob 'gss*'

Which (I think) suggests that 'gss-ffmpeg' exists.
I have VM's setup for 18.04, 20.04 and 24.04 so I tried to install on each of those as a test.  20.04 and 24.04 give the same message, 18.04 doesn't find anything (tells me to add a repo).
Am I missing a repo somewhere?  Any pointers?
Thanks in advance.

There is no package gss-ffmpeg in the Ubuntu repositories. It may be a dependency of a PPA or other non-Ubuntu package that you installed.

What is the software that you are trying to install? Are you sure the package you are looking for is not gst-ffmpeg? I believe that was an earlier incarnation of gstreamer-ffmpeg - whose functionality is now provided by the gstreamer1.0-libav package. See also What happened to gstreamer-ffmpeg and can I replace it?

Thanks both above.  @steeldriver - the software is some proprietary scanning software that comes with a series of .deb packages.  One of those depends on gss-ffmpeg.  I suspect it's a missing .deb package they have generated, so I'll go back to the vendor.  I just assumed it was an Ubuntu package and I was missing a repo.

See at: https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/gss-ntlmssp_0.7.0-4_amd64.deb.html
